# Splunk how to display multiple stats queries in table?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to Splunk and don't quite manage to formulate a Splunk query in order to get the exact results I want:

I have server logs that are something like this:
clientIP instanceID serviceType error

I have three queries that I would like to display together:

**A** gives me all instanceIDs that are unused beyond being created and destroyed

```
| stats count(eval(error="")) as Total_Successful_Calls
count(eval(serviceType ="X")) as numcallsXService
by clientIP instanceID 
| where numcallsXService=2 and Total_Successful_Calls=2
```

**B** gives me all instanceIDs that are actually used

```
| stats count(eval(error="")) as Total_Successful_Calls
count(eval(serviceType ="X")) as numcallsXService
by clientIP instanceID 
| where numcallsXService=2 and Total_Successful_Calls>2
```

**C** actually gives me the complete count of instances for checking if the results are valid

```
| stats dc(instanceID) by clientIP
```

Now I would like to display these likes so:

```
clientIP numberAllInstances numberUsedInstances numberUnusedInstances
```

I fail at counting the results of A and B - how is this done in Splunk?

Then I would also like to put where conditions like in A and B into C - here I think it may not be possible with dc and I may instead have to use the query structures of A and B.

Finally, I have no clue how to put these queries together - do I put A, B and C after another like this: A|B|C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`append`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/append) followed by a grouping [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) and [`eventstats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eventstats):

```
<first SPL>
| append
    [| search <second SPL> ]
| stats values(*) as * by clientIP instanceID
| eventstats dc(instanceID) as instances by clientIP
```

###EDIT

If you have some more representative sample data, we may be able to help you simplify your search better, too